# How to capture value of optionals in a switch statement in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I have a function where I parse a `String` into a `Bool`, `Double` or `Int` before falling back to a `String`. Currently I use a if-else conditions like this

```
func parse(stringValue: String) {

    if let value = Bool(stringValue) {
        // do something with a Bool
        print(value)

    } else if let value =  Int(stringValue)  {
        // do something with a Int
        print("\(stringValue) is Int: \(value)")
    } else if let value = Double(stringValue) {
        // do something with a Double
        print("\(stringValue) is Double: \(value)")
    } else {
        // do something with a String
        print("String: \(stringValue)")
    }
}
```

This is ok but my personal preference is to use switch statements in Swift but I don't know how to do so without force unwrapping:

```
func parse(stringValue: String) {

    switch stringValue {
    case _  where Bool(stringValue) != nil:
        let value = Bool(stringValue)!
        // do something with Bool
    case _ where Int(stringValue) != nil:
        let value = Int(stringValue)!
        // do something with Int
    case _ where Double(stringValue) != nil:
        let value = Double(stringValue)!
        // do something with Double
    default:
        // do something with String
    }
}
```

How can I capture the result of the `where` so that I can use it in the `case` scope?

Comment: stick with the `if` version - it's perfectly clean

Comment: I was also about to suggest that you move your special test to see if a double is really an integer into its own function, but I see you've now removed that...